# getImageData() returning all 0's

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, getimagedata

So, I have a function like this:

```
var getRGBArray = function (img) {
    // create the canvas we need to work with 
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

    // get the canvas context
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // will store the image data and the returned array
    var imgData, rgbArray = [];

    // make sure that the width and height are correct
    context.canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
    context.canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;

    // draw the image
    context.drawImage(img, img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight);

    // get the image data 
    imgData = context.getImageData(0, 0, img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight);

    // imgData contains r,g,b,alpha values. We skip
    // the alpha value. 
    for (var i = 0, n = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i+=4, n+=3) {
        rgbArray[n] = imgData.data[i];
        rgbArray[n+1] = imgData.data[i+1];
        rgbArray[n+2] = imgData.data[i+2];

        // imgData.data[i+3] is the alpha channel. We ignore it. 
    }
    return rgbArray;
};
```

Which is just supposed to take an image and return an array that's set up like `[r0, g0, b0, r1, g1, b1, ..., rn, gn, bn]`.

First, the array that is returned is completely empty, which is obviously a problem.

Second, when I input all of this stuff into the console window on Firefox, the `imgData` array is a reasonable length, but all of the data is 0! None of the values are coming up undefined, and I have a simple webpage I'm debugging on. The webpage already has the image loaded, and I'm just getting the image using `document.getElementById('testImage')`.

Can someone please explain to me why this is happening?

EDIT: This is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30466490/create-canvas-element-with-image-and-append-to-parent) because I was wondering why `drawImage()` was giving me back a data array with all 0's. They are asking completely different things.

Comment: Can you produce a simple test case and put it up on a site like http://jsfiddle.net? The fact that the function returns an empty result suggests to me that `img.naturalWidth` and `img.naturalHeight` are `0` and the image has not actually loaded yet.

Comment: This demonstrates the problem pretty well: https://jsfiddle.net/yte93epm/5/

Comment: I found the issue. In `context.drawImage()` I wasn't passing in the start position. The fix is to change it so it's like: `context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight)`. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @k3n: I'm pretty liberal about what I consider a 'dupe', but I think there's a mistake here. Although the bug in the 'duplicate' question is ultimately the same as the bug in the code here, the questions themselves are quite different. I think this is like marking 'What is √16' as a duplicate of 'How many Ghostbusters were there in the original film'.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. In `context.drawImage()` I wasn't passing in the start position. The fix is to change it so it's like: `context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight)`. Thank you for your help!